# Pretty Faces Mapping problem

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

i using PrettyFaces for Pretty URL
but i have first problem with PrettyFaces:
my mapping in pretty-config.xml

```
     <url-mapping id="home">
  <pattern value="/" />
  <view-id>/faces/index.jsf</view-id>
  </url-mapping>
```

i have one file index.xhtml 
when deploy on server url http://localhost/myproject
it not found index.jsf
what's happen ?

mapping in web.xml of prettyfaces

```
<!-- PrettyFaces-->

<filter>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
 <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
 <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>





<!-- End PrettyFaces-->
```

GlassFish Message for problem

```
HTTP Status 404 - /index.jsf not found

type Status report

message/index.jsf not found

descriptionThe requested resource (/index.jsf not found) is not available.
```

Comment: if you remove pretty faces things then is it working ?

Comment: no i just change <view-id>/faces/index.jsf</view-id> to <view-id>/faces/index.xhtml</view-id>

Answer (score 1):

The `index.jsf` file doesn't exist. Make it in the root directory of your project (http://localhost/myproject/index.jsf).